# Using msal_mobile with Flutter

Tags: flutter

When runing the MsalMobile example i have this error :
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'MsalMobileException'
Help me please

Comment: do you have internet connection when this error appears ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is incomplete. You need to identity the exact error causing the exception. Try catch will help you do that, check out the official docs for error handling [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/msal_mobile/latest/)

Comment: this is the error :E/flutter (12477): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'MsalMobileException'
E/flutter (12477): #0      MsalMobile.create (package:msal_mobile/msal_mobile.dart:48:7)
E/flutter (12477): <asynchronous suspension>

Comment: I understand, but what type of MsalMobileException is it? There are many, you need to narrow down on the code/type of exception it is before you can know what you need to fix. Adding try catch will help with that. Follow documentation pasted in the link of this answer.